# ASP MVC 3 prevent multiple inserts on page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I have a simple ASP MVC3 **list** controller, with an **add** method, with an id parameter.

List:

```
http://localhost/MVCAPP/ListFoo/
```

Add method

```
http://localhost/MVCAPP/ListFoo/Add?id=1
```

In my Add method, I update my **Viewmodel** with the added element, then makes a call to:

```
return View("ListFoo", viewModel);
```

The updated list is displayed, and everything's almost fine.

The problem is that with such a return, the URL in the address bar is still

```
http://localhost/MVCAPP/ListFoo/Add?id=1
```

And if the user hits F5, another item will be added, which I'd like to prevent.

I know I can filter out such a behavior in the controller, but I'd rather prefer to redirect the browser address bar to:

```
http://localhost/MVCAPP/ListFoo/
```

Do you know any way to do this?

By the way, I'm not sure trying to control the address bar content is the right way to look at this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Action.RedirectToAction method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) to redirect the client after the work is done in the controller.

Besides that, you could use POST as FormMethod to send data to the server.

Comment: @Vinzz: FYI this is also known as the **Post-Redirect-Get** pattern. SO if you'll be looking for additional info about it make sure you query this term... +1 to you Rhapsody...

Comment: Thanks for the directly usable answer, and also for the POST suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

That is why you need to use **PRG**: *Post-Redirect-Get* when you are doing any such form post.

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

So the best option is to **redirect** the user to a **GET** method to display the page.